# Проектирование клиент-сервера для  игры "шахматы"

Tags: клиент-сервер, qt, c++

Есть реализация архитектуры клиента для игры в шахматы,логика которого полностью описана в классе **Game** , который содержит в себе поля:обьект класса **Board**(доска) и Список обьектов класса **Piece** - **Piecelist**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QObject>
#include "piece.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "rook.h"
#include "knight.h"
#include "bishop.h"
#include "queen.h"
#include "king.h"
#include "pawn.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QIODevice>
class Game : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Game(QObject *parent = 0);
    QGridLayout* drawBoard();
    void start();
    void clearStyleSheet();
    //QByteArray bytes;
    friend QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out,Game &game);
    friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &out,Game &game);
    //int k;

    //friend QDataStream operator<<(&out, const Game &any);

    QList<Piece*> PieceList;
    Board* board;
signals:

public slots:
    void is_pressed(QPoint coord) ;
private:

};

#endif // GAME_H
```

Теперь я хочу отправлять с помощью сервера реализованного как **QTcpServer** обьект класса **Game** клиенту(другому игроку).
Делаю так:
1)в классе Game создаю перегрузки операторов QDataStream:

```
 QDataStream  &operator <<(QDataStream &out,Game &game)
 {
    out << game;
    return out;
 }
```

2) Собственно вызов:

```
Game* game=new Game();
QByteArray bytes;
QDataStream out(&bytes,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out<<(*game);
```

И после этого "успешно" вылетает программа.
Как решить данный вопрос.Как передать обьект класса по сети используя QtcpSocket и QDataStream?

Comment: для передачи объектов в питоне я создавал wsgi сервер и передавал данные по soap протоколу. Не в тему, но вдруг на мысль натолкнёт какую-нибудь=) Например, работать по soap, там всё чётко.
З.Ы. Как сделать в данном случае не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, даже передав этот класс, указатели Piece из QList<Piece*> PieceList; не передадутся нормально на сервер. Не знаю в этом ли проблема при передаче, но лучше Вам пересмотреть само взаимодействие между клиентами (скорее всего придётся передавать отдельно Piece, так как это указатели).

Почему бы Вам, к примеру, не обмениваться изменениями в положении конкретных фигур?

Comment: В самом деле, обмена порциями из 4-х байт, вида e2e4 будет вполне достаточно для 2-х программ.

Comment: согласен. можно, конечно, усложнить, сделать передачу имени фигуры "p1" (пешка№1), начального положения, конечного положения.. и может кого она съела, чтобы лишний раз проверить на другой стороне. Но это уже избыточность.

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно. То, что у Вас ошибка выскакивает, это очень правильно. Ошибка очень простая и без подводных камнев.

> no match for 'operator<<' in 'out << * game.Game::board'

Это Ваша ошибка. О Чём она говорит? С нами общается, собственно объект out, т.е. класс QDataStream. Этот класс нам говорит "Нету такой перегруженной функции, которая бы умела записывать объект game". Но это же бред, потому что Вы сами перегрузили функцию, которая принимает объект game для записи, следовательно, она должна узноваться. Оказывается, что это совсем не бред, а всё дело в том, как Вы реализовали перегрузку функции QDataStream  &operator <<(QDataStream &out,Game &game).

```
QDataStream  &operator <<(QDataStream &out,Game &game)
 {
    out << game;
    return out;
 }
```

Это Ваша перегрузка. Когда Вы пишите out << *game, то компилятор ищет и находит соотвествующую функцию(которую вы перезагрузили) и начинает выполнять тот код, который Вы там записали. Вы там ничего особенного не записывали, а просто записали out << game. Так компилятор же этого не умеет делать для "чужих" объектов. Он опять ищет и находит Вашу функцию, и снова натыкается на строчку out << game и т.д. и т.п. в общем, Вам нужно в перегружаемой функции записывать те данные, которые QDataStream понимает, по определённой структуре(как бы разобрать объект Game на составляющие, которые понимает QDataStream и записать их), чтобы Вы, потом могли считать эти же самые составляющие и по Вашей какой-то определённой структуре, собрать объект game.

Вот Вам простой пример.

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_H
#define SIMPLE_H
#include <QString>
#include <QDataStream>

class Simple
{
public:
    Simple();
    Simple(int a_, int b_, QString s_);
    friend QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, Simple &obj);
    friend QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Simple &obj);

private:
    int a;
    int b;
    QString s;
};

#endif // SIMPLE_H
```

ccp:

```
#include "simple.h"

Simple::Simple()
{
}

Simple::Simple(int a_, int b_, QString s_) : a(a_), b(b_), s(s_)
{
}

QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, Simple &obj)
{
    out << obj.a << obj.b << obj.s; /* если бы я написал, как Вы, "out << obj", то была бы опять ошибка, проверьте. */
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, Simple &obj)
{
    in >> obj.a >> obj.b >> obj.s;

    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает сделать вот так?

Объявляем QByteArray, потом в него использую QDataStream считываем длину объекта класса храня ее скажем в quint16, затем сам объект. Отправляем это все через write.
На том конце устанавливаем  связь с помощью сигнала readyRead.

В документации написано, что он вызывается, не когда в сокет приходит **вся** информация, а когда приходит хоть что-то. И вот там уже используя все тот же QDataStream мы дожидаемся пока придет 16 бит, что бы считать длину сообщения в quint16, проверяем все ли пришло и только тогда считываем в объект класса.

Вот так это все и выглядит:

**server.cpp**

```
void Widget::slotSendToClient()
{
    QByteArray arrBlock;
    QDataStream clientSendStream(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    serverSendStream << quint16(0) 
                     << game;

    clientSendStream.device()->seek(0);
    clientSendStream << quint16(arrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));

    tcpSocket->write(arrBlock);
    messageLineEdit->clear();
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
void Widget::slotReadServer()
{
    next_block_size = 0;
    QTcpSocket *tcpSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QDataStream serverReadStream(tcpSocket);
    while(true)
    {
        if (!next_block_size)
        {
            if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
            {
                break;
            }
            serverReadStream >> next_block_size;
        }

        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < next_block_size)
        {
            break;
        }
        Game game;
        serverReadStream >> game;

        next_block_size = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: а что делать с указателями внутри объекта game? Останусь при мнении, что не стоит такой "метакласс" передавать по сети.

Comment: Указатели нужно убирать. Или придумывать другой способ. Я шахматы по другому делал. Передавал координаты и все было замечательно.

Comment: ТС, все приходят к одному и тому же мнению. Задумайся=) или объясни причину выбора именно такого способа.

Comment: Я бы настоятельно не рекомендовал в GUI-потоке (class Widget) выполнять while(true), т.к. это может "подвесить интерфейс".
  Лучше завести локальный буффер в классе и дописывать данные в него при получении по сети, а когда он будет нужного размера (т.е. все данные примутся), его нужно будет обработать и очистить

Comment: @spirit,Задумался... и решил передавать координаты как QList<QPoint>.
Попробовал.Получилось.
Но вот мне не дает покоя то,что я никак не могу в перегрузке оператора **<<** разыменовать указатель.Длеаю так: **out <<*(game.board)**. Выдает ошибку: no match for 'operator<<' in 'out << * game.Game::board' Что не так?

Comment: точно для класса Board переопределёно? дайте код.

Comment: @spirit,Нет смысла.У меня оказывается класс Board содержит в себе массив обьектов класса Cell: Cell* cells[8][8].
Теперь я окончательно решил передавать координаты.Хотя в принципе существует же возможность как-то передать обьект класса в QDataStream,даже если в нем есть указатели?

Comment: Судя по ответу Ukeo да. Но, как я говорил, передадутся только адреса объектов, которые на другой машине будут ссылаться "непоймикуда"=) Хотя и это надо проверять, я не пробовал, только читал.